# scipy.minimize maximum return value

Tags: python, scipy

I am using the scipy optimize function and providing it with a custom minimisation function. I call the minimizer with

```
result = op.minimize(calc_chi2, start_list, args=())
```

the `calc_chi2()` function looks like

```
def calc_chi2(parameters):
    if within_priors(parameters):
        # calculate chi2
    else:
        return math.inf
```

This function tests whether the parameters within certain priors and if not it should return a very large chi^2. I use math.inf, which however leads to the minimizer putting the parameter vector to nan everywhere, so I guess the minimizer doesn't like math.inf??? If I just use a large number everything works fine... I am just wondering what the correct approach is here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider throwing/catching an exception to handle the case of infinite chi^2 - it isn't clear what you would expect to happen, if not the NaN behavior you described, and handling an exception would allow you to be explicit about what you want to happen.

```
class InfiniteChiException(Exception):
    """This exception is raised under certain conditions, yadda yadda yadda"""
    pass

def calc_chi2(parameters):
    if within_priors(parameters):
        # calculate chi2
    else:
        raise InfiniteChiException

try:
    result = op.minimize(calc_chi2, start_list, args=())
catch InfiniteChiException:
    # do something here
```

Comment: but it is me who returns the infinite chi^2... I don't need to catch that? I am just looking for a better solution than just hard coding in a large chi^2 if the parameter is outside the prior...

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen when an infinite chi occurs?

Comment: I am returning infinite chi^2 because I want the minimization algorithm to know that this parameter set is outside the prior and therefore should have zero likelihood

Comment: Understood, but the minimization algorithm needs to have a mechanism for "knowing" that a parameter set is outside the prior. So my question is not about your intent, it's about your algorithm - what do you want your *algorithm* to do when an infinite chi occurs? That's the question you answer by filling out the "do something here" portion. (Most likely, you want to drop those values instead of setting them to Inf. But it depends on your problem.)

Comment: I have to return a value in any case right? The scipy.minimize function does expect a return value? I just want to return something which guarantees that the algorithm does not see that as the minimum... without hard coding in a value

Comment: You don't want to pass infinity to op.minimize because it does not understand your intention in doing that. You want to short-circuit the optimization routine if there is an infinite chi-squared value. I'm showing you how to short-circuit the optimization routine. The "# do something here" is where you would remove any values that you don't want op.minimize to consider, and try calling it again.